# jQuery toggle() img element on document.ready - chrome issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-selectors

I try to toggle some elements(labels/fields/img) with jQuery based on the jQuery ends with selector.
Everything works fine in IE/Firefox/Safari - but not on Google's Chrome. There's an issue with img elements on the document.ready() function.
Chrome does not toggle those img elements.

Any Idea, suggestions? Thank you.

jQuery 1.5.1
Chrome 12.0.742.100

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var v = $('#VNType').val();
    if (v == 'equalToVP') {
        ToggleVisibility();
    }
});

function ToggleVisibility() {
    //jquery ends with selector
    //hide label/fields/img
    $('[id$="VN"]').toggle();
    $('[for$="VN"]').toggle();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably due to the fact that `ready` fires prior to images being loaded.  Try `load` instead and see if it fixes the issue.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```